# Javascript print multiple divs on different pages

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-paged-media

I need to print on A4 paper with each `<div>` starting on different pages

```html
<div id="1">
  //content
 </div>
 
 <div id="2">
  //content
 </div>
 
 <div id="3">
  //content
 </div>
 
 ....
```

For example, `<div id="1">` could be 2 or 3 pages in content, but `<div id="2">` still needs to start on a new page.

Answer (score 7):

In your CSS:

```
#1 {page-break-after: always;}
#2 {page-break-after: always;}
#3 {page-break-after: always;}
```

Where #1 is the ID of your div

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css:

```
div {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

The page-break-after property sets whether a page break should occur AFTER a specified element.

Read this for full information -  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript, use CSS:

```
@media print {
  /* top-level divs with ids */
  body > div[id] {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

This uses a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and the [page break property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) to ensure that non-empty `<div>`s with `id`s will always start on a new page when viewing (or printing) on [paged media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media).

Save below as an HTML file and open it in your browser with the print dialog. You'll see that each `<div>` begins on a new page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @media print {
      /* top-level divs with ids */
      body > div[id] {
        page-break-before: always;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="1">
    content
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    content
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    content
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```